# FireDAC FDSCript error while executing last script

Tags: delphi, firedac

When I execute the following code I get an error when executing the last script.

The error is:

"Cannot open the file "c:\FiredacDemo\las.sql"

I cannot understand why it executes fine named scripts  @fdrop_dables, @first, @second and only for the very last it tries to executes instead an sql file.

`procedure TForm1.btnMasterScriptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
        with FDScript.SQLScripts do begin
          Clear;
          with Add do begin
            Name := 'root';
            SQL.Add('@drop_tables');
            SQL.Add('@first');
            SQL.Add('@second');
            SQL.Add('@last');
          end;
          with Add do begin
            Name := 'drop_tables';
            SQL.Add('drop TABLE T1;');
            SQL.Add('drop TABLE T2;');
            SQL.Add('drop TABLE T3;');
            SQL.Add('drop TABLE T4;');
          end;
          with Add do begin
            Name := 'first';
            SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
            SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
          end;
          with Add do begin
            Name := 'second';
            SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T3 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
            SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T4 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
          end;
          with Add do begin
            Name := 'last';
            SQL.Add(format('INSERT INTO T1 (ID, FNAME, CREATED) VALUES(%d, %s, current_timestamp);', [ 1, 'fabio', now]));
            SQL.Add('commit;');
          end;
        end;`

```
    FDScript.ValidateAll;
    FDScript.ExecuteAll;
```

end;

EDIT: This one works!

`procedure TForm1.btnMasterScriptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
        FDScript.SQLScriptFileName := '';
        FDScript.Arguments.Clear;`

```
    with FDScript.SQLScripts do begin
      Clear;
      with Add do begin
        Name := 'root';
        SQL.Add('@drop_tables');
        SQL.Add('@first_script');
        SQL.Add('@second_script');
        SQL.Add('@third_script');
        SQL.Add('@last_script');

        SQL.Add('@');  // Added this -> see below
      end;
      with Add do begin
        Name := 'drop_tables';
        SQL.Add('drop TABLE T1;');
        SQL.Add('drop TABLE T2;');
        SQL.Add('drop TABLE T3;');
        SQL.Add('drop TABLE T4;');
      end;
      with Add do begin
        Name := 'first_script';
        SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
        SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
      end;
      with Add do begin
        Name := 'second_script';
        SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T3 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
        SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE T4 (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(50), CREATED TIMESTAMP);');
      end;
      with Add do begin
        Name := 'third_script';
        SQL.Add(Format('INSERT INTO T1 (ID, NAME) VALUES(%d, %s);', [ 1, '''fabio''']));
      end;
      with Add do begin
        Name := 'last_script';
        SQL.Add(Format('INSERT INTO T1 (ID, NAME) VALUES(%d, %s);', [ 2, '''stefano''']));
      end;

      with Add do begin  // addes this (see above)
        Name := '';      // please note the empty '' Name
      end;               // 

    end;

    FDScript.ValidateAll;
    FDScript.ExecuteAll;
```

end;

Comment: Clear the `SQLScriptFileName` property.

Comment: Added FDSCript.SQLScriptFileName := ''; just before with FDScript.SQLScripts do begin but still the error persits

Comment: "Cannot open the file "c:\FiredacDemo\las.sql"  LAS.sql or LAST.sql ?

Comment: Then open your unit's .dfm file and search for that file name. It must come from somewhere..

Comment: Yes Vlad the strange thing to note here is that is LAS.sql *not* LAST.sql

Comment: Opening the dfm shows no 'LAS.sql" the FADScript has been configured *only* in code

Comment: It sounds then that after preprocessing the engine requests a last script to be named just `las`, not `last` (as it seems to be searching for a file `las` rather than executing a script called `last` which is part of your script collection). I would give them different names, with some prefix e.g. so they won't collide with the FB keywords anymore (so long you haven't changed your server since your last question). No Delphi by hand..

Comment: Thank you Victoria, I found a workaround: I have modified the original post adding an edited code that works. I renamed also the scripts names  as for your suggestion. Another solution that works is to name the last script omitting the last char you have declared in the root script, so, if you named it in the root script @last_script, you then the last script name will be 'last_scrip' (omitting the final 't' char)

Comment: Then I would call this a preprocessing bug (no Delphi by hand right now). What happens with the original version if you call the subscripts by `@@`, `START` or `INPUT`?

Comment: If I call  the subscripts by @@, START or INPUT the error persists, so in the end I too think it is a preprocessing bug. Anyway, at least there is a workaround. (I am on Delphi Berlin Upd2)